# Could not load file or assembly 'RadTabStrip.Net2' or one of its dependencies

Tags: telerik

I am working on Radstrip controls. When i complie the code I am getting error like " Could not load file or assembly 'RadTabStrip.Net2' or one of its dependencies." Can anyone help me how to fix this error.

SelectedIndex="0" Width="1280px"> 
     
    
        Height="321px" Width="700px" BorderStyle="Solid" OnPageViewItemCreated="RadMultiPage1_PageViewItemCreated1">

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the RadTabStrip.Net2.dll file cannot be found in the bin folder of your web site. If the file is there, make sure it has the same file permissions as the rest of the .dll files in the folder so the ASP.NET application can read it. If the file is not in the bin folder, copy it from the RadControls for ASP.NET installation.

Comment: i dont have RadTabStrip.Net2.dll in my bin folder. I installed latest version of rad controls. Still i am not getting this dll. I dono why? I installed trail version. Please let me know how to install this RadTabStrip.Net2.dll. Thanks
This is what i downloaded
http://www.telerik.com/account/free-trials.aspx


in above link i downloaded RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX